# writing div for layout and positiong

Tags: css

I am trying to edit a page to use the full width of the page.  I am having problems setting out the div layout.  There is a div there already

```
<div id="rightPanal" style="margin-top: 425px;">
```

but it has things too far to the right and it is a narrow column going down the middle of the page.

I deleting/editing/ a lot of div's already there and I end up with nothing and its all over the place on different broswers.

Can I go to the .css file and just write some css that would give me a box in the middle (where inside i can put in two columns) of the page that doesn't interfere with other div and layout on the screen   - say start X and Y on the screen - 4 pictures of equal size and text underneath the four boxes - all square ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Position: absolute](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp)

```
#rightPanal {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
}
```

Comment: what does that do exactly - does it get the 50% of the screen ? what do you work from when trying to aim for a part of the screen ?

Comment: **top** will position the div on the middle of the page (vertically)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want absolute positioning:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

This code should get you close:

```
#rightPanal {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: yes, i hope it doesn't mess up other browsers or other layout

Comment: This works in all browsers. And the point of `absolute` is so that the element is not figured into the layout.